# PHPMailer error con require '../vendor/autoload.php';

Tags: phpmailer

Instale el composer y se creo la carpeta vendor/autoload.php, pero cuando lo agrego a la programación da un error cargando. Ademas instale el composer.json

```
require 'php/conexion.php';
require "PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/OAuth.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/POP3.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/Exception.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

--Aqui da error
require '../vendor/autoload.php'; 


--Esto contiene el autoload.php
<?php
// autoload.php @generated by Composer
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';
return ComposerAutoloaderInitebb7b572e935351f22fde076b7cfc2f2::getLoader();
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Podrías agregar el mensaje del error que estás recibiendo? De esa forma podremos tener una idea de lo que sucede. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para añadir lo necesario a tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: revisa desde qué ruta estás llamando al autoload. Prueba con `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`